# How to transform this request to a request from ClientSession request ? (aiohttp, asyncio)

Tags: python, request, python-asyncio, multipartform-data, aiohttp

I tried to make this request :

```
payload = {
    'query': 'mutation add_file($file: File!, $item_id: Int!) {add_file_to_column(item_id: $item_id, file: $file, column_id: fichier3) {id}}',
    'variables': '{"item_id":' + str(itemID) +'}',
    'map': '{"file":"variables.file"}'
}

files=[('file',(filename,open(file_src,'rb'),'file/csv'))]

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
```

to this aiohttp request (ClientSession):

```
payload = {
    'query': 'mutation add_file($file: File!, $item_id: Int!) {add_file_to_column(item_id: $item_id, file: $file, column_id: fichier3) {id}}',
    'variables': '{"item_id":' + str(itemID) +'}',
    'map': '{"file":"variables.file"}'
}

files=[('file',(filename,open(file_src,'rb'),'file/csv'))]

async with ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
     async with session.request(method='POST', url=url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files) as r:
           r_json = await r.json()
```

But everytime I got this error :

```
> TypeError: _request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'files'
```

As you can see I can't pass files argument to ClientSession.request, so my question is how to pass my arguments files and payload ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Use `FormData` only, insert payload and files, then pass FormData variable to data parameter.

Code using FormData:

```py
payload = {
    'query': 'mutation add_file($file: File!, $item_id: Int!) {add_file_to_column(item_id: $item_id, file: $file, column_id: fichier3) {id}}',
    'variables': '{"item_id":' + str(itemID) +'}',
    'map': '{"file":"variables.file"}'
}

data = FormData()
data.add_field('file',
                open(file_src,'rb'),
                filename=filename,
                content_type='file/csv')
for (k, v) in payload.items():
    data.add_field(k, v)
async with ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
    async with session.request(method='POST', url=url, headers=headers, data=data) as r:
        r_json = await r.json()
```